# AngularJS add ng-include dynamically after app is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an update button with a directive. When the button is clicked, the targeted element should receive some new html which includes a ngInclude element. It does not seem to be loading the file though, all it does is include a comment like this `<!-- ngInclude: nav.html -->`. If I log the `tpl` variable I get `{ 0: <!--  ngInclude: nav.html  -->, length: 1 }`.  Here is my directive and element generator code.

Directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive("contentControl"
,["$compile"
,function($compile){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("click", function () {
                var $container = $(this).closest('#editor_contenteditorcontainer');
                var html = "";
                $container.find('.row').each(function () {
                    var $args = $(this).find('form').serializeObject();
                    html += ' ' + generateContent($args);
                });
                angular.element(document.getElementById('responsiveviewport')).html(html);
                $compile(html)(scope);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Generator

```
function generateContent($arg){
  switch($arg['name']){
    case 'Partial':
        return '<div ng-include src="\''+$arg['content']+'\'"></div>';
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to do `$scope.$apply()` from click event to run digest cycle

Comment: @pankajparkar thanks for the response. I have updated my answer. I found that the `$compile` needed to be after adding it to the element. I have added `scope.$apply()` also. It will now load the files but it still does not apply the contents of those files into the `ng-include`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to compile the place where you inserted generated content.

```js
.directive('contentControl', ['$compile' ,function($compile){
    return {
      template: 'Click here',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind('click', function () {
              var html = "<p>Template:</p><div ng-include src=\"'template.html'\"></div>";

              var templateGoesHere = angular.element(document.getElementById('templateGoesHere'));
              templateGoesHere.html(html);

              $compile(templateGoesHere)(scope);

              scope.$apply();
          });
      }
    }
}]);
```

[See Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZpF7ci4fhCMpBZjFdTCI)

Comment: My problem was that i forgot to call scope.$apply() in my solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`$compile(element)(scope)` returns an element that you should place in the DOM. The `.html()` part of your code is just inserting your uncompiled html, and you're not doing anything with the compiled element. Instead, you could do something like:

```
angular.element(el).empty().append($compile(html)(scope))
```

Comment: I was not able to get this to work doing it this way. Compiling the element instead of the html worked.